# Second integer counts as 0

Tags: c, switch-statement, calculator

I just started learning C, but I've already encountered a problem.
I want to write a simple calculator, but -I don't know why- the second integer always counts as 0.
I just can't find out what could be the problem.

Here's my code:

```
int main(){

    int a, b;
    char c;

    printf("Enter 2 numbers:\n");
    scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);
    printf("Enter an operator:\n");
    scanf("%s", &c);

    switch(c){
    case '+':
        printf("%d\n", a+b);
        break;
    case '-':
        printf("%d\n", a-b);
        break;
    case '*':
        printf("%d\n", a*b);
        break;
    case '/':
        printf("%d\n", a/b);
        break;
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help:)

Comment: How does a session look like? Show a sample problematic input and the resulting output please. Please make a [mre].

Comment: scanf("%s", &c);?? Can you see the problem?

Comment: Yes, I've already corrected my second scanf:)
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use `scanf("%d%d", &a, &b)` without a space between. Note that the input must contain whitespace between the numbers (otherwise `12 3` would be indistinguishable from `1 23`). Also, you should note that `%s` is designed to work with strings, and is [not safe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430303/disadvantages-of-scanf#answer-2430978). Try to use `scanf(" %c", &c)` to work with a single character, not a string (also note the space before the percent, that swallows all the whitespace before the operator character).

Comment: Not a single whitespace. You missed the need of the correct format specifier.

Comment: Most of this "answer" counts as _advice_, the actual problem is the erroneous use of `%s` to read a character - the resulting overrun corrupts the adjacent data.  We now have an OP who thinks the solution is the space - which it is not (primarily).   The _answer_ as such is not as prominent as it should be.  You should make that the first point.  The _advice_ might even be more appropriate for a comment on the question rather than part of this answer - it should at least be secondary.

Comment: *You can use `scanf("%d%d", &a, &b)` without a space between.* What difference would that make?

Comment: Yes, I said it wrong, the space AND the incorrect usage of %s/%c:)

Answer (score 1):

You are reading a string into a single character: `%s` will read, f.ex. `+` and `\n` into `c` thus overwriting your stack.

You should also check the return value of `scanf()` for errors, i.e. if the user has entered incorrect data and the parser failed.

With these changes the code works as described:

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int a, b;
    char c[20];
    int result;

    printf("Enter 2 numbers:\n");
    result = scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);
    if (result != 2) {
        perror("integer input failed");
        return(1);
    }
    printf("Enter an operator:\n");
    result = scanf("%s", c);
    if (result != 1) {
        perror("character input failed");
        return(1);
    }

    /* just showing that everything was recognized correctly... */
    printf("'%d' '%d' '%s'\n", a, b, c);

    switch(c[0]){
    ...
```

Example run:

```
$ gcc -Wall -Werror -o dummy dummy.c
$ ./dummy
Enter 2 numbers:
1 2
Enter an operator:
+
'1' '2' '+'
3
$
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `%s` for reading into a `char`. That is undefined behaviour.
You need to use correct format specifiers to avoid that. In this case `%c`.
Additionally, to skip the newline/return which you find in the input after scanning a number, use a blank beforehand, i.e. `" %c"`.

End of the answer, with undefined behaviour, anything can happen.

Just for fun however, try this code and use 2 and 257 as input:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

    int a=99, b=98;
    char c='x';

    printf("Enter 2 numbers:\n");
    scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);
    printf("You entered %d %d. Now enter an operator:\n", a, b);
    scanf(" %s", &c);
    printf("After scanning a null-terminated string into a char variable, a and b are now %d %d.\n", a,b);

}
```

If we are lucky and you get the same effect of undefined behaviour as I do, then you have now learned something about where the 0 at the end of the operator string ends up. Namely in one of the bytes of the variable `b`.

With the proposed input you probably get 2 and 256. The 2 has survived, the 257 got the lower byte zeroed and ends up being 256.

Also try entering 2 3 and "+A". You are aware that 'A' has an ascii value of 65, aren't you?

As a final hint, study this article. It is very helpful for anythig you want to read in.
http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html